# Why is my disk full after transforming the picture in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, disk-space

I am new to Photoshop and I was just practicing to make a new page and crop a imported picture and copy it to my blank page.

I am sure that my computer is not weak because it has a good ram,CPU and graphic card but I do not know why while I was trying to transform the picture, I had processing page that was doing transforming.

[image]

While it was processing, I was seeing that my drive C was getting full and suddenly from 60GB that I had in my drive C turned to 200MB.

My Photoshop is installed on my D Drive but I do not know why this is happening.

I tried to change the scratch disk to D too but it was not helpful.

When i restarted my computer the disk was ok and I had that 60GB  but I can not work properly with Photoshop CC 2020 yet.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: That's a colossal image, 35433x59055px. I've never tried manipulating anything anywhere near that size, but I'm really not surprised you are running out of scratch disk.

Answer (score -2):

Your disk is full because you are working with data in volumes that fills it. It's quite simple.

To solve the problem either resize your data to a size more appropriate to the abilities or your computer, or expand the capabilities of your system or replace your system with one that has those capabilities.